# How to make phone calls using my landline in C#

Tags: c#, phone-call

I have looked the internet but I didn't find an answer for my question. I need to know where to start from. Some said I should use TAPI I did use it but I couldn't make no call. I want to connect my landline phone and using C# make a phone call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup I have Westell 7500

Comment: Sorry, I mean telephone (landline) modem.

Comment: Oh its alright. Yes I do have

Answer (score 1):

This is where I would start

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is an example 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/TAPI-3-in-C-Get-Lines-and-dd143eaf

Comment: I saw those links before, but they didn't  help at all. I tried running the example but it also doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work it doesn't build ? it gets a error ? whats the error ?

Comment: It says 'Call Failed' on some lines and on other lines it just doesn't do anything

Comment: When I connect my phone and start the application it doesn't show my phone in the lines. And when I click on any line and hit "Use Line" it gives me this error "Value does not fall within the expected range."